# Animation move left and right

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I am making a windows form animation where a animation of a character is walking left and then walk right once he reached the end of the windows form.
and i have to put a play/pause button for the animation to stop and continue where he left off

I have 16 frames each of the character walking right and left

I would like to ask how to put a boundary on the picturebox and how to get the picturebox to change to the walking right animation once it reach the left edge of the windows form and change the walking left animation once it reach the right edge of the windows form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declare a new integer for frame and set it to 1
    int frame = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Increase the frame per tick
        frame++;

        //Loop : If the frame exceeds 16, set the frame back to 1 
        if (frame > 16)
        {
            frame = 1;
        }
        //REtrieve the image fromfile base on the value of the ineger "frame"
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + 
                            "\\left" + frame + ".png");

        int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
        x -= 5;
        //else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 1;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I would like to ask how to put a boundary on the picturebox and how to get the picturebox to change to the walking right animation once it reach the left edge of the windows form and change the walking left animation once it reach the right edge of the windows form

Comment: I highly recommend that you use the tiny, awesome [Dotnet Transitions library](https://github.com/UweKeim/dot-net-transitions) instead of rolling it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

PictureBox has a border property. Check if it works for you.

You can check if PictureBox Left matches Forms Left that would mean it needs to move right and change the image on this condition.

Answer (score 0):

To detect when the control has reached the boundaries, you may check if the Location.X property + Width is equal to or greater than the PictureBox container (in this case, Form)'s width.

```
if(pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width >= pictureBox1.parent.Width)
{
    direction = "left";//reached the end so go left
```

Of course you can easily test if we're at the starting position by checking if `pictureBox1.Location.X == 0`

Comment: sorry but i see no difference

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 different images 1 directed to left and 1 directed to right...
create an extra variable stating direction 
then you can turn the image direction if the folowing criteria is met 
`if direction = right and picture.location >= (how far you want it to go probably border)`

then

`direction = left`

change to the left directed image

change your movement variable to negative
`if direction = left and picture.location <= 0`

then

`direction = right`

change to the rightdirected image

change your movement variable to positive